# Adding some rigor to Wasserman's "All of Statistics" example problem

Tags: probability

I am revisiting some combinatorics/statistics concepts now that my math maturity has improved a bit, and I want to prove some of the "101" claims with a bit more rigor. Consider the following example problem from Wasserman's *All of Statistics*:

> Toss a fair coin $10$ times. Let $A = $"$\text{at least one head.}$" Let $T_j$ be the event that tails occurs on the $j^{th}$ toss. Then: \begin{align}\mathbb P(A)&=1-\mathbb P (A^c) \\ &=1-\mathbb P(\text {all tails})\\ &=1-\mathbb P(T_1 T_2 ... T_{10}) \text{ using independence } \\ &=1-\mathbb P(T_1) \mathbb P(T_2) \cdots \mathbb P (T_{10})\\&=1-\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^{10} \approx .999 \end{align}

**I find that there are a lot of implicit claims made in this example that are not justified.** I would like to know if my below approaches are appropriate means of formalizing Wasserman's proof.

---

Although not explicitly stated in the text, I am going to construct some definitions here:

Let $\Omega_n$ be defined as the sample space for an experiment with $n$ flips of a fair coin.

Let an outcome $\omega$ of an "experiment with $n$ fair coin flips" be defined as an $n$-tuple, where each index of the $n$-tuple must have an $h$ or a $t$ (but not both) as its entry.

> My **first claim** is that the total number of unique outcomes for an experiment with $n$ coin flips is $2^n$.

Next, let $T^n_j$ be defined as the set of unique $\omega \in \Omega_n$ where the $j^{th}$ index of each $\omega$ is occupied by a $t$. i.e. Let $T^n_j:=\{ \omega \in \Omega_n | \omega(j) = \text{'t'} \}$, where $\omega(j)$ denotes the value at the $j^{th}$ index of a given outcome $\omega$.

> My **second claim** is that for any $j$ such that $1 \leq j \leq n$, $\quad \mathbb P(T^n_j)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Finally, I am going to assume (although not explicitly stated in the text) that the definition of a fair coin is what motivates Wasserman's assertion that $\mathbb P(T_1 T_2 ... T_{10}) = \mathbb P(T_1) \mathbb P(T_2) \cdots \mathbb P (T_{10})$. Further, I assume that a feature of a fair coin flip is that the $\mathbb P(\{\omega_1\})=\mathbb P(\{\omega_2\})= \cdots = \mathbb P(\{\omega_k\})$ where $k$ represents the number of all possible outcomes in for a particular $\Omega_n$...which by Claim 1 would be $2^n$. Note that $\omega_i$ is used to denote a single outcome and therefore is unrelated to the notation $\omega(i)$.

---

*Claim 1* Proof by Induction

Consider an experiment with $1$ coin flip. There are $2$ possible $1$-tuples: '$h$' and $t$'. $2=2^1$.

Next, assume that for an experiment with $n$ coin flips, there are $2^n$ unique $n$-tuples.

Prove that for an experiment with $n+1$ coin flips, there are $2^{n+1}$ unique $(n+1)$-tuples.

By assumption, we know that there are $2^n$ unique $n$-tuples. In order to become an $(n+1)$-tuple in the context of a coin flip, you either append an '$h$' or a '$t$' to a previously described $n$-tuple: these are the only options. As such, there are $2^n$ unique $(n+1)$-tuples that have an '$h$' in their $n+1^{th}$ index and there are $2^n$ unique $(n+1)$-tuples that have a '$t$' in their $n+1^{th}$ index. Therefore, there are a total of $2^n+2^n=2^n(1+1)=2^n\cdot 2=2^{n+1}$ unique $(n+1)$-tuples associated with an experiment of $n+1$ coin flips.

Note that in the above paragraph, it should be clear that the act of "appending" does not undo uniqueness. That is to say, suppose $(- - -)$ and $(---)'$ are unique $n$-tuples but after appending, we claim that $(---)h$ and $(---)'h$ are not unique $(n+1)$-tuples. Because the final index of these two $(n+1)$-tuples have the same value, this clearly means that the preceding indices must be the same (i.e. not distinct/unique), which contradicts our assumption.

---

Claim 2: Proof by Generalization

For an arbitrary $n$, prove that for any $j$ satisfying $1 \leq j \leq n$, $\mathbb P(T^n_j) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Consider the following picture: $(---\cdots t_j \cdots ---)$, which describes an arbitrary $n$-tuple with a $t$ at the $j^{th}$ index. Using Claim 1, we can make the following argument:

There are $j-1$ indices "behind" $t_j$. There are $n-j$ indices "in front" of $t_j$. Consider these two chunks of indices as separate tuples of size $j-1$ and $n-j$. A $j-1$-tuple corresponds to an experiment with $j-1$ fair coin flips and an $n-j$-tuple corresponds to an experiment with $n-j$ fair coin flips. By claim 1, this means that there are $2^{j-1}$ outcomes associated with the $j-1$ experiment and $2^{n-j}$ outcomes associated with the $n-j$ experiment.

Now, we can append either an $h$ or a $t$ to the $j-1$ tuples at the $j^{th}$ index. This means that there are $2^{j-1}$ $j$-tuples that have $t$ as their $j^{th}$ index. To *each* one of these $2^{j-1}$ outcomes, we can append $2^{n-j}$ different outcomes. This means that we have:

$$2^{n-j}+ 2^{n-j}+ \cdots +2^{n-j} \quad (2^{j-1} \text{ times })$$

different outcomes with $t$ in the $j^{th}$ index. Equivalently, we have $2^{n-j}\cdot 2^{j-1}=2^{n-1}$ $n-$tuples with $t$ as their $j^{th}$ index. By claim 1, we know that there are $2^{n}$ total outcomes of an experiment with $n$ fair coin flips therefore:

$$\frac{2^{n-1}}{2^{n}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

of the outcomes have $t$ at the $j^{th}$ index. Up to this point, I have only proved that the *number of outcomes* populating an event $T^n_j$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ of the total number of possible outcomes associated with $\Omega_n$.

In order to prove that $\mathbb P(T^n_j)=\frac{1}{2}$, I will make use of my definition that $\mathbb P(\{\omega_1\})=\mathbb P(\{\omega_2\})= \cdots = \mathbb P(\{\omega_{2^n}\})$. It should then be clear that if half of the outcomes have $t$ in the $j^{th}$ index, then $\mathbb P(T^n_j)=\frac{1}{2}$, which makes use of a general definition of finite sample spaces: $\mathbb P (A) = \frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}$

Comment: A $\textit{fair}$ coin is a coin that when flipped once, the probability of $T$ is $p(T)=\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: $P(T_1 T_2 \cdots T_n)= p(T_1)p(T_2)\cdots p(T_n) = p(T)^n$ is due to independence, or equivalently exchangeability.

Comment: @mjw so then the two features I assigned to the "definition" are, in fact, things I need to prove?

Comment: I cannot really see what you will prove other than what Wasserman has in his text.  Yes, you could go with the formal definitions, defining a sigma algebra, etc., which are in many standard textbooks, but the calculation should more or less result in the same thing, imho.  Others may disagree?

Comment: @mjw Fair enough. But I do not understand how one can conclude the value of $\mathbb P (T_j)$ without the steps I employed above. At least it is not obvious to me.

Comment: That's what a fair coin is.  For each flip, the probability of heads is one half.  The probability of tails is one half.  The probability it lands on its edge is zero.

Comment: @mjw So even though your definition is specific to only one coin flip, I can generalize the definition to any number of coin flips? I guess I am confused as to why this is the case. (Sorry for the hassle - new to this field)

Comment: Well yes, you could, but taking the definition of a fair coin for one flip, along with either "independent flips" or "exchangeability" you have $p(TT\cdots T)=\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^n, \quad \forall n.$

Comment: If you $\textit{have to}$ prove it, you can prove it by induction.